# Angular oidc-client Popups not redirecting in iframe after successful login into azure AD

Tags: javascript, angular, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have implemented Azure AD with my angular web application oidc-client. on clicking login window a popup open with URL [ `https://login.microsoftonline.com`.] it ask for Azure ad username and password, After successful login a code is return as parameter but popup never route back to main **iframe** page it just stays there.

Has anyone encountered this scenario?

This was working but stopped suddenly. after google chrome browser version: 115.0.5790.102 but it working fine with google chrome browser version: 114.0.5735.199

If **google chrome browser version: 115.0.5790.102** or onward all version it gets below console errors

`Error: No matching state found in storage at main.9935dbb703e3535d.js:1:7414405 at X.invoke (polyfills.01468bccb7704509.js:1:96908) at Object.onInvoke (main.9935dbb703e3535d.js:1:8005760) at X.invoke (polyfills.01468bccb7704509.js:1:96846) at q.run (polyfills.01468bccb7704509.js:1:92226) at polyfills.01468bccb7704509.js:1:107342 at X.invokeTask (polyfills.01468bccb7704509.js:1:97531) at Object.onInvokeTask (main.9935dbb703e3535d.js:1:8005565) at X.invokeTask (polyfills.01468bccb7704509.js:1:97451) at q.runTask (polyfills.01468bccb7704509.js:1:92866)`

Can there be a proxy issue or browser issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "No matching state found in storage" suggests that the Azure AD authentication flow is not being completed successfully and also issue with the state parameter during the OpenID Connect (OIDC) authentication flow.

This issue may be related to the way the state parameter is being handled or stored during the authentication process. The state parameter is crucial for security and to ensure the response from the identity provider matches the request.

To resolve this **Use a Secure Session Storage** Storing the state parameter in a secure session storage can help ensure its integrity.

I have used `sessionStorage` and im able to login with out any issue.
This service will handle authentication with OIDC.

```js
    // auth.service.ts
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { UserManager, User } from 'oidc-client';
    import { authConfig, generateAndStoreState } from './auth-config';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class AuthService {
      private userManager: UserManager;
      private user: User;
    
      constructor() {
        this.userManager = new UserManager(authConfig);
      }
    
      async login() {
        const state = generateAndStoreState();
        await this.userManager.signinRedirect({ state });
      }
    
      async completeLogin() {
        this.user = await this.userManager.signinRedirectCallback();
        const savedState = sessionStorage.getItem('oidc-client-state');
    
        if (this.user && this.user.state !== savedState) {
          console.error('State mismatch error');
        }
      }
    
      async logout() {
        await this.userManager.signoutRedirect();
      }
    
      isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        return this.user && this.user.access_token && !this.user.expired;
      }
    
      getAccessToken(): string {
        return this.user ? this.user.access_token : '';
      }
    }
```

```js
// auth-config.ts
function  generateState() 
{ 
const state = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7); 
sessionStorage.setItem('oidc-client-state', state); 
return state; 
} 

export  const  generateAndStoreState = () => { 
const state = generateState(); 
return state; 
};
```

**Result**

[image]